# RhinoMocks and Lambda Expression

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, rhino-mocks

With the interface below:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate);
}
```

Implemented like so:

```
private IRepository<Foo> Repository {get;set;}
public FooService(IRepository<Foo> repository)
{
    Repository = repository;
}    

public void Foo(int bar)
{
    var result = Repository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(bar));
    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Returned null, not what I expected!");
    }
}
```

If I write a test like this:

```
repos = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<Foo>>(null);
repos.Expect(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id.Equals(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))).Throw(new Exception("This exception should be thrown!"));

FooService f = new FooService(repos);
f.Foo(1);
//expecting exception to be thrown
```

I do not get the expected exception thrown, so I am presuming that mocked call is being ignored/not called.

However if I add `IgnoreArguments()` it *is* called and I do get the expected exception.

```
repos.Expect(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id.Equals(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))).IgnoreArguments().Throw(new Exception("This exception should be thrown!"));
```

Any thoughts as to what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: See post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593477/mocking-lambda-in-rhino-mocks

Comment: possible duplicate of [unit test with lambda fail using rhino mock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338095/unit-test-with-lambda-fail-using-rhino-mock)